# Expandable dynamic nested list with objects array

Tags: javascript

Im struggling with expandable nested array list anyone keen to help me out

https://jsfiddle.net/AccordEuro06/2otnxb9c/3/

```
const webfolder = [{
    name: 'Webpage',
    type: 'folder',
    children: [{
            name: 'php',
            type: 'folder',
            children: [{
                    name: 'header.php',
                    type: 'file'
                },
                {
                    name: 'footer.php',
                    type: 'file'
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            name: 'css',
            type: 'folder',
            children: [{
                    name: 'images',
                    type: 'folder',
                    children: [{
                            name: 'logos',
                            type: 'folder',
                            children: [{
                                    name: 'Colored.svg',
                                    type: 'file'
                                },
                                {
                                    name: 'Monochrome.svg',
                                    type: 'file'
                                },
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            name: 'gallery',
                            type: 'folder',
                            children: [{
                                    name: 'image1.jpg',
                                    type: 'file'
                                },
                                {
                                    name: 'image2.png',
                                    type: 'file'
                                },
                                {
                                    name: 'image3.gif',
                                    type: 'file'
                                },
                                {
                                    name: 'image4.jpeg',
                                    type: 'file'
                                },
                                {
                                    name: 'image5.jpg',
                                    type: 'file'
                                },
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            name: 'about-us.jpg',
                            type: 'file'
                        },
                    ],
                },
                {
                    name: 'style.css',
                    type: 'file'
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            name: 'javascipt',
            type: 'folder',
            children: [{
                    name: 'script.js',
                    type: 'file'
                },
                {
                    name: 'script2.js',
                    type: 'file'
                },
                {
                    name: 'ajax.js',
                    type: 'file'
                },
                {
                    name: 'jquery.js',
                    type: 'file'
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            name: 'index.html',
            type: 'file'
        }
    ]
}];

function listHtml(children) {
    return '<ul>' + children.map(node =>
            '<li>' + node.name +
            (node.type === 'file' ? '' : listHtml(node.children)) +
            '</li>').join('\n') +
        '</ul>';
}


document.getElementById('expandableTree').innerHTML += listHtml(webfolder);
```

I understand that hide/show on click should be done with css but i ran out of ideas how to add proper classes to branches and leafs

Comment: Take look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42401535/how-to-create-a-nested-dropdown-menu-on-click-with-focus-css-only?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the HTML5 [`<details>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details) elements:

```js
function listHtml(children) {
    return '<ul>' + children.map(node =>
        `<li>
            ${node.type === 'file' 
                ? node.name
                : `<details>
                     <summary>${node.name}</summary>
                     ${listHtml(node.children)}
                   </details>`
            }
        </li>`
    ).join('\n') + '</ul>';
}


document.getElementById('expandableTree').innerHTML += listHtml(webfolder);
```

Try it [on CodePen](https://codepen.io/FZs111/pen/oNjKrrg)

Comment: mate you are a genius!